# Completely Clear command prompt through bash

Tags: bash, scripting, aix, menu

I am actually making a menu for my official server.
I made it through bash scripting on AIX. 
The problem i am facing is that when script is running, user can scroll up and see history of all commands he used/entered etc. Even though i clear the screen but scrolling up still shows the previous commands.
Is there any way that i can permanently clear the screen so that even scrolling up cannot show anything.

Comment: `tput reset ; history -c`

Comment: Are you talking about the command line _history_, the command line _prompt_, or the terminal's _scroll back buffer_?

Comment: That's not about which shell you use (shells don't have screens or scrollback buffers) but which terminal or terminal emulator you use. Which is it? `xterm`, `aixterm`, GNU `screen`, `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: With `xterm`, `printf '\33[3J` would clear the scrollback buffer. On my system, `tput clear` sends `\033[3J\033[H\033[2J`. With `gnome-terminal`, I need `printf '\e[H\e[2J\e[3J'` to properly wipe everything. With GNU `screen`, you'd probably need to set the scrollback length to 0 temporarily: `screen -X scrollback 0`...